# Coreference resolution for tokenized text in stanford

Tags: stanford-nlp

what i have given is a tokenized text, something like

> "In the summer of 2005 , a picture that people have long been looking
>   forward to *T*-1 started *-2 emerging with frequency in various major
>   media ."

and I need to get as result the coreference resolution from Stanford but I want to start from the steps after tokenizing, can someone help me in that I got the tokens and I am trying to create sentence annotation but it gives null,can somebody help (I read the post [Coreference resolution using Stanford CoreNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954649/coreference-resolution-using-stanford-corenlp/35407771?noredirect=1#comment58518345_35407771)) it was helpful but not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `tokenize.whitespace` property. This will tell the tokenizer to tokenize on whitespace; i.e., treat the text as already tokenized.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I need, also if it is possible I have another questions about Stanford can you please help me with them if you have time(not programming questions)